# Update problems: packages held back

Tags: upgrade, aptitude, updates

When I try and upgrade I get packages that are kept back, when I use dist-upgrade they will be upgraded however I get this warning:

```
Current status: 5 updates [-1].
will@will-desktop:~$ sudo aptitude dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reading extended state information      
Initialising package states... Done
The following packages are BROKEN:
  libdrm-nouveau1 
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libkms1{a} 
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libdrm-dev libdrm-intel1 libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 
5 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B/245kB of archives. After unpacking 2,077kB will be freed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libdrm-nouveau1: Breaks: xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (< 1:0.0.16) but 1:0.0.15+git20100219+9b4118d-0ubuntu5 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

Remove the following packages:
xserver-xorg-video-all
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau

Score is 188
```

I don't know whether to upgrade or not, looks like it might break my video

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would not update. Especially if you currently have packages in a working condition. Never run a partial update or install packages kept-back. They are like so for a reason. Are you running Maverick BETA? If so that would explain it. You should wait for the packages to sort themselves out, and they will.

(I am actually taking a break writing a blog article that explains things like this right now, odd).

Comment: dist_upgrade should only be used in stable archives (i.e. a released version). In any kind of development release apt-get upgrade should be used instead because it prevents packages to be installed if there might be dependency problems.

Comment: OK cheers. I'd be grateful if you link the blog post after writing, i would love to read it.

Comment: Did not have time to be as comprehensive as I wanted, however it is a quick read, hopefully helpful.
http://vbrummond.blogspot.com/2010/09/tips-for-ubuntu-administrators.html

Answer (score 0):

performing:

sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau

will remove the dependency blockage and allow you to upgrade. You can reinstall the packages after the upgrade:

sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-all

Comment: `xserver-xorg-video-all` is a meta-package, which will install all available video drivers. For re-installation, use the `--reinstall` switch: `sudo apt-get --reinstall install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`